# All purpose recursive function

Tags: python, function

There are two recursive functions **fn(f, n)**, the first one evaluates this expression
sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(1))))) = 0.587181

```
from math import sin


def fn(f, n):
    def fn_inside(x):
        for i in range(n):
            x = f(x)
        return x
    return fn_inside


f1 = fn(lambda x: "sin(%s)" % x, 5)
f2 = fn(lambda x: sin(x), 5)
print("%s = %f" % (f1("1"), f2(1)))
```

The next one calculates the ratio (1/1, 2/1... 13/8...) of adjacent numbers from the Fibonacci series (0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144 - each number is the sum of the two preceding ones, starting from 0 and 1) at the distance (precision) from the beginning as the golden ratio

```
distance = 4

def fn(f, n):
    def fn_inside(*x):  # there is the difference
        for i in range(n):
            x = f(*x)   # there is the difference
        return x
    return fn_inside


def next_fib(i, j):
    return j, j + i


def golden_ratio(n):
    get_fib_n = fn(next_fib, n+1)
    i, j = get_fib_n(0, 1)
    return j / i


print(golden_ratio(distance))
```

As you can see here the difference in the accepted argument f(*x).
And I got stuck hard to **write a universal function** that will work in both the first and second cases. golden_ratio(n) can be changed too. Because if we remove the * then for the second case we get an error

```
TypeError: fn_inside() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

otherwise the error is different

```
x = f(*x)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given
```

Comment: Why would you want this?  It's harder to test and debug, and it violates the single purpose principle of functions.  I don't see the benefit.

Comment: @TomServo Looks like your average textbook exercise on higher-order functions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that there is no recursion here. `fn` is a higher-order function — it operates on functions — but it is not recursive, i.e, it does not call itself.

In your first snippet, the function `f` takes a single argument and returns a single value. In the second snippet, it takes two arguments and returns a tuple. This is why you need to structure the code differently.

The obvious way to work around this would be to make `next_fib` take a single argument, which is a tuple, instead of two arguments.

Comment: It does return a tuple, which OP then unpacks into two arguments on the next call. Or do I misunderstand your concern?

Comment: It returns a tuple, but it does not accept a tuple as a parameter. If it accepted a tuple, then `x = f(x)` would work (input type = output type).

Comment: It accepts two arguments. So this two-value-tuple is unpacked (`f(*x)`)  into two arguments, so it's fine

Comment: One of us is misunderstanding the OP:s concern (could very well be me...). I was under the impression that they wanted to make a universal function `fn(f, n)` that returns a composite function which is equivalent to applying `f` `n` times. This is a lot easier if `f` returns the same type as it accepts.

Comment: (Sorry for the weird edit. Needed it to remove my downvote, that get's locked after some time)